# jenkins triggering builds for all old git commits when a fresh commit is pushed. I am using the GITScm plugin in jenkins

Tags: git, jenkins, github

I had a requirement across organisation in which I needed to migrate our github project repository from one domain say https://github.myorg-old.com to a new one https://github.myorg-new.com

So, I migrated all the git commits and branches history of the repository to the new domain.

I updated the Url of the new github hook into an existing jenkins job which is meant to be triggered on each push to any branch of the repository.

Now, the problem is when I pushed a new change in this newly migrated git repository, the jenkins job is building all the old commits and running them sequentially. As there are thousands of commits in the repository, building all of them will take forever.

I only wanted the jenkins job to trigger for my most recently pushed code and not all the old commits. Please suggest how can I do this ?